# Magento 2.3.0 - Create Product Page H1 title with product name and attribute name

Tags: magento2, product, php, magento2.3, meta-title

I have created two phtml files that can be called from within a CMS Block on a product page to echo the product name and an attribute name.

As follows:

Product Name

> {{block class="Vendor\ProductName\Block\ProductName"
>   template="Vendor_ProductName::productname.phtml" }}

Attribute Name (Artist)

> {{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="artist"
>   template="Magento_Catalog::artist.phtml"}}

I want to be able to create a title within the H1 tag for the product name, as follows

> Buy 'Product name' by 'Artist'

The following is the title.phtml code thats currently used.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title
 */
$cssClass = $block->getCssClass() ? ' ' . $block->getCssClass() : '';
$title = '';
if (trim($block->getPageHeading())) {
    $title = '<span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" ' .  $block->getAddBaseAttribute() . '>'
        . $block->escapeHtml($block->getPageHeading()) . '</span>';
}
?>
<?php if ($title): ?>
    <?php if ($this->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view'): ?>
        <h1 class="tt-title"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $title ?></h1>
    <?php else: ?>
```

And this is how it outputs on the frontend

```
<h1 class="tt-title"><span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" itemprop="name">Terrace of a café at night (Place du Forum)</span></h1>
```

Is there a way or using the phtml calls that I use in the CMS Blocks to create the product page H1 title?

---

UPDATE

I used the following to get part of the title

> Buy "Product Name" by

By using the following code,

Changed the H1 Title as follows

```
title="Buy <?php echo $block->getPageHeading(); ?> by">
```

This is the code I'm using to get the current product page attribute

```
<?php
$product = $block->getProduct();
$product_name = $product->getName();
$attr_exists = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('artist');

if ($attr_exists){
    $attr_name = $product->getAttributeText('artist');
}

echo $product->getAttributeText('artist');
?>
```

How can I use the above code to add the artist name to the H1 title?

Answer (score 0):

I called the following block

> {{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="artist"
>   template="Magento_Catalog::artist.phtml"}}

into the title.phtml block using the following

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::artist.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

so the final code to get the H1 title using the product name and attribute name is

```
title="Buy <?php echo $block->getPageHeading(); ?> by <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View")->setTemplate("Magento_Catalog::artist.phtml")->toHtml(); ?> ">
```

Resulting in the desired result creating a dynamic product name title

> Buy "Product name" by "Artist"